# What is this URL list filter parameter?

Tags: 2010, filter, url

I have a I am trying to build but I need to know what to populate in one of the parameters...

For Example...

```
AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Client_x0020_Name&FilterValue1=44&FilterOp1=In&FilterLookupId1=1&FilterData1=0%2C08b601b3-5b7e-4850-9c27-3424b5a1e6ad
```

I need to know how to populate the **FilterValue1=44** parameter... I am trying to build this url with the purpose of filtering on taxonomy fields...

So far I know the parameters are:

- FilterField1=TaxonomyField.InternalName
- FilterData1=TaxonomyField.SspId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, After a bit of investigating I was able to determine that this is the ID of the term in the rootwebs hidden list "TaxonomyHiddenList".

This list can be located by going to:

```
SPSiteURL/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx
```

To get the value of this item you can use the following method:

```
int[] id = TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm(SPSite, TermStore.Id, TermSet.Id, Term.Id, false, 1);
```

**References:**

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.getwssidsofterm.aspx)

[http://pholpar.wordpress.com](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/some-words-about-taxonomyfieldvalue-and-its-wssid-property/)

Comment: Hi, Please accept your own answer as answer, so the question will not reflect in unanswered questions.