# How do I set FilterOperator1 in the URL?

Tags: list, filter, url

I know I can filter a SharePoint list by adding `?FilterField1=fieldname&FilterValue1=value` to the URL. Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms500520.aspx) also lists a property `FilterOperator1` that you can use if you want an operator other than `equals`.

However, if I add `&FilterOperator1=Lt` to the query string, I just get an error. How do I specify this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it `FilterOp1` in the URL.

e.g. for less-than: `?FilterField1=fieldname&FilterValue1=value&FilterOp1=Lt`

MSDN has the [full list of operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.filterfieldqueryoperator%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: Spent ages googling this before finding an example in [another question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65512/what-is-this-url-list-filter-parameter). This seems to be completely undocumented.